# Festivos en Colombia

Tags: php

En este enlace https://pastebin.com/WQnp0s0W encontré la siguiente clase para calcular festivos:

```
<?php
class Festivos
{
    private $hoy;
    private $festivos;
    private $ano;
    private $pascua_mes;
    private $pascua_dia;

    public function getFestivos($ano=''){
        $this->festivos($ano);
        return $this->festivos;
    }

    public function festivos($ano='')
    {
        $this->hoy=date('d/m/Y');

        if($ano=='')
            $ano=date('Y');

        $this->ano=$ano;

        $this->pascua_mes=date("m", easter_date($this->ano));
        $this->pascua_dia=date("d", easter_date($this->ano));

        $this->festivos[$ano][1][1]   = true;       // Primero de Enero
        $this->festivos[$ano][5][1]   = true;       // Dia del Trabajo 1 de Mayo
        $this->festivos[$ano][7][20]  = true;       // Independencia 20 de Julio
        $this->festivos[$ano][8][7]   = true;       // Batalla de Boyacá 7 de Agosto
        $this->festivos[$ano][12][8]  = true;       // Maria Inmaculada 8 diciembre (religiosa)
        $this->festivos[$ano][12][25] = true;       // Navidad 25 de diciembre

        $this->calcula_emiliani(1, 6);              // Reyes Magos Enero 6
        $this->calcula_emiliani(3, 19);             // San Jose Marzo 19
        $this->calcula_emiliani(6, 29);             // San Pedro y San Pablo Junio 29
        $this->calcula_emiliani(8, 15);             // Asunción Agosto 15
        $this->calcula_emiliani(10, 12);            // Descubrimiento de América Oct 12
        $this->calcula_emiliani(11, 1);             // Todos los santos Nov 1
        $this->calcula_emiliani(11, 11);            // Independencia de Cartagena Nov 11

        //otras fechas calculadas a partir de la pascua.

        $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-3);           //jueves santo
        $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-2);           //viernes santo

        $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(43,true);      //Ascención el Señor pascua
        $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(64,true);      //Corpus Cristi
        $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(71,true);      //Sagrado Corazón

        // otras fechas importantes que no son festivos

        // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-46);       // Miércoles de Ceniza
        // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-46);       // Miércoles de Ceniza
        // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-48);       // Lunes de Carnaval Barranquilla
        // $this->otrasFechasCalculadas(-47);       // Martes de Carnaval Barranquilla
    }
    protected function calcula_emiliani($mes_festivo,$dia_festivo) 
    {
        // funcion que mueve una fecha diferente a lunes al siguiente lunes en el
        // calendario y se aplica a fechas que estan bajo la ley emiliani
        //global  $y,$dia_festivo,$mes_festivo,$festivo;
        // Extrae el dia de la semana
        // 0 Domingo  6 Sábado
        $dd = date("w",mktime(0,0,0,$mes_festivo,$dia_festivo,$this->ano));
        switch ($dd) {
        case 0:                                    // Domingo
        $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 1;
        break;
        case 2:                                    // Martes.
        $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 6;
        break;
        case 3:                                    // Miércoles
        $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 5;
        break;
        case 4:                                     // Jueves
        $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 4;
        break;
        case 5:                                     // Viernes
        $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 3;
        break;
        case 6:                                     // Sábado
        $dia_festivo = $dia_festivo + 2;
        break;
        }
        $mes = date("n", mktime(0,0,0,$mes_festivo,$dia_festivo,$this->ano))+0;
        $dia = date("d", mktime(0,0,0,$mes_festivo,$dia_festivo,$this->ano))+0;
        $this->festivos[$this->ano][$mes][$dia] = true;
    }   
    protected function otrasFechasCalculadas($cantidadDias=0,$siguienteLunes=false)
    {
        $mes_festivo = date("n", mktime(0,0,0,$this->pascua_mes,$this->pascua_dia+$cantidadDias,$this->ano));
        $dia_festivo = date("d", mktime(0,0,0,$this->pascua_mes,$this->pascua_dia+$cantidadDias,$this->ano));

        if ($siguienteLunes)
        {
            $this->calcula_emiliani($mes_festivo, $dia_festivo);
        }   
        else
        {   
            $this->festivos[$this->ano][$mes_festivo+0][$dia_festivo+0] = true;
        }
    }   
    public function esFestivo($dia,$mes)
    {
        //echo (int)$mes;
        if($dia=='' or $mes=='')
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (isset($this->festivos[$this->ano][(int)$mes][(int)$dia]))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }       
    }   
}
?>
```

¿Cómo puedo usar la clase **Festivos** para saber cuáles días de un mes son festivos o no?

Por ejemplo:

- 01/01/2019 es festivo
- 02/01/2019 no es festivo
- 03/01/2019 no es festivo...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
//Creas una instancia de la clase que bajastes para calcular los dias festivos
$festivos = new Festivos();
//Asignas a esta variable la fecha que debes comprobar
$myfecha = strtotime('2018-04-05');
/* Si el año de la fecha es diferente a el de la fecha corriente tienes
   que llamar a la función festivos y pasarle ese año es decir:
   $festivos->festivos(date('Y', $myfecha));
*/
if($festivos->esFestivo(date('d', $myfecha), date('m',$myfecha)){
    echo date("d-m-Y", $myFecha)." Es festivo";
} else {
    echo date("d-m-Y", $myFecha)." No es festivo";
}
```

O puedes crear una función dentro de la clase Festivos como la siguiente:

```
public function esFestivoFecha($fecha){
    $fecha = is_int($fecha) ?: strtotime($fecha);
    $dia = date('d', $fecha);
    $mes = date('m', $fecha);
    if(date('Y', $fecha) !== date('Y')){
        $this->festivos(date('Y', $fecha));
    }
    return $this->esFestivo($dia, $mes);
}
```

Y para usarla seria asi:

```
$festivos = new Festivos();
$myfecha = strtotime('2018-04-05');
if($festivos->esFestivoFecha($myfecha)){
    echo date("d-m-Y")." Es festivo";
} else {
    echo date("d-m-Y")." No es festivo";
}
```

O:

```
$festivos = new Festivos();
$fecha = '2018-04-05';
if($festivos->esFestivoFecha($fecha)){
    echo "{$fecha} Es festivo";
} else {
    echo "{$fecha} No es festivo";
}
```

La diferencia es si quieres pasar un timestamp o un string como mas comodo lo encuentres.

Comment: Gracias Dariel Ramos, funciona perfecto con la función `esFestivoFecha` y con el último método. Gracias por tu tiempo y por compartir tu conocimiento.

Comment: Jajja para eso estamos aqui..

Comment: Revisa la respuesta mia modifique el codigo de la función esFestivoFecha porque antes llamaba a $this->festivo y realmente es con s, es decir $this->festivos

Answer (score 0):

Colegas, les comparto una clase para **Laravel de Festivos Colombia**, esta muy completa y disponible en GIT

https://github.com/rmunate/CalendarioColombiaFestivos